# Unable to load templatefile

Tags: module, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7, php-7.1

I'm facing an error on prestashop 1.7

We created some modules for our own e-commerce, now i was going to create another and i'm getting a complete white screen and this error on apache error logs:

> [php7:error] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SmartyException: Unable to load template file 'helpers/view/gstructureddata.tpl' in /route/vendor/prestashop/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php:129\nStack trace:\n#0 /route/classes/helper/Helper.php(113): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch()\n#1 /route/classes/helper/HelperView.php(59): HelperCore->generate()\n#2 /route/classes/controller/AdminController.php(2482): HelperViewCore->generateView()\n#3 /route/modules/gstructureddata/controllers/admin/AdminGStructuredDataController.php(42): AdminControllerCore->renderView()\n#4 /route/classes/controller/AdminController.php(2090): AdminGStructuredDataController->renderView()\n#5 /route/modules/gstructureddata/controllers/admin/AdminGStructuredDataController.php(25): AdminControllerCore->initContent()\n#6 /route/classes/controller/Controller.php(205): AdminGStructuredDataCon in /route/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 3224, referer: http://domainname.local/admin/index.php?controller=AdminPerformance&token=ab2995a7ad68d5c4c9dbdfc03ab82b96&conf=4

What i know and what i tried to solve this issue:

The template route is ok, i know it because i completelly cloned a working module, only refactoring classnames, filenames and folder names from the other module name to this one.

- **Cache** deleted and generated again.
- **class_index** deleted and generated again.
- disabled and enabled almost all things (trying each time) on
  backoffice -> advanced -> performance.
- launched **build_bootstrap.php** from projectDir/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/ **(seems to do nothing)** in an attempt to remake bootstrap.php.cache
- Read like 30 issues about this with another stack trace so it does not cover same issue at all, major of which solution is to change template route or editing php things on server due to a first upload from local or server migration, and none of them on modules.
- **Uninstall and install** the module again.
- **Delete the module** folder, clone another module, refactor and all repeating all things i told you before.
- Checked and rechecked all names, classnames, filenames and foldernames (usually if you fail here it throws another error when you go to modules on backoffice and it does not happen, i can install and uninstall the module without issues, errors or warnings).
- Cry silently.

None of these things seems to work so i'm a little bothered with that now. 3 people checked here with no sight of what to do like "hey there's a character that you ommited" or something like this usual problems when coding.

Any advice/help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gosh damn, i refactored AdminGStructuredDataController to AdmingstructureddataController and now it works. It was properly defined in gstructureddata.php as AdminGStructuredData (now i set Admingstructureddata).
If anyone knows why it's now working and why the error shown points to a non-existing/not found template, please tell me.